# How to stop Process.Start process for python code from c#

Tags: c#, python, process, environment-variables, exe

In C# application I have running of python console application exe file with process by environment variable path:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "folder\\python.exe");   
    Process.Start(filePath); 
}
```

and I want stop this process and close console with button click or any other condition, not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "folder\\python.exe");
    var process = Process.Start(filePath);
    process.Kill();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the second button click, you are starting a new process (and killing it immediately) instead of stopping the process you started with the first button click. To stop the process that was started from the first button click, you will need to store the `Process` object that was created in a variable, and then call the `Kill()` method on that object when the second button is clicked.

This is a very simple example (Note that each time `button1` is pressed, it would assign the newly created process to the `runningProcess` variable)

```
public class FormClass
{
    Process runningProcess;

    public FormClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "folder\\python.exe");   
        runningProcess = Process.Start(filePath); 
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!runningProcess.HasExited)
        {
            runningProcess.Kill();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hello. it should work. I did exactly the same you showed, but nothing, process is still running

Comment: Did you monitor your processes in Task Manager? You should see the process for your Python script disappear after you click the second button. If your script opens/uses other resources, they may not be properly closed/released when your script is killed, however.

Comment: it is in Task Manager and it is disappear after click the second button in Task Manager list, the python process has no any outputs or inputs out of own implementation, to C# or from C#, except reading and writing into the text document, but this execution  does not occurs in the process often, and for sure at the moment of pressing to second button this part of implementation is not executed. But console window is open and process running.

Comment: If it disappears from Task Manager after the second button click, that means that the process was terminated. If the script sometimes writes to a text doc, but doesn't write after the kill button is clicked, that should also indicate that it was killed (If it wasn't killed, it would still write to the text doc, even after the button click)

Comment: it is disappears after click on button and immediately appears in Task Manager list, there is nothing to run it again. And it is still writes into the text document